# How to hide the values in for loop

Tags: php, html

actually i tried one concepts forloop i want hide only 2 values i don't know how to do that one

```
<?php

  for($i=0;$i<=20;$i++){
   echo $i;
  }
//if $i=10 means hide and $i=15 means hide this value remaining value i want to show how to do
```

Comment: It sounds like an upper/lower case issue, just  do `if(strtolower($imageFileType) = 'jpg'`..etc

Comment: try using [finfo_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) for better mime detection.

Comment: K i got correct ans, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why giving &&. Remove with OR.

```
if($imageFileType != "jpg" || $imageFileType != "png" || $imageFileType != "jpeg" || $imageFileType != "gif" ) 
{
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit line and run :

```
if (($imageFileType!= "jpg") && ($imageFileType != "jpeg") && ($imageFileType != "JPG") && ($imageFileType != "gif") && ($imageFileType != "png"))
```